# Excel - Sumproduct two arrays from the same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to produce a sumproduct between two arrays derived from the same column of values. For example:

```
A     B     C
1     FC    100
1     ST    5
2     FC    120
2     ST    3
3     FC    26
3     ST    7
```

In this scenario, I need a formula that calculates (100*5)+(120*3)+(26*7), or in other words performs a sumproduct of values in column C when column B is "FC" and values in column C when column B is "ST".

I've searched for quite a while and have been unable to find a suitable answer. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT((B1:B5="FC")*(C1:C5*C2:C6))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - tbh, I followed the narrative and completely ignored the pattern in column B.

Comment: @Jeeped not bad for over the phone while waiting to get my hair cut. Hence the comment and not an answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner wrote up an answer with explanation - will withdraw it if you choose to write a full answer. Clever solution, thought it was worth stepping through for someone to learn from - impressed you managed that on a phone keyboard without Excel available to check it. :)

Comment: @brichins - I maintain (and I believe Scott concurs) that users who provide answers in comments cannot fault fully scoped answers that closely (or even exactly) duplicate the content of the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Scott Craner commented (please accept his answer, if he writes one):

> ```
> SUMPRODUCT((B1:B5="FC")*(C1:C5*C2:C6))
> ```

This approach uses array references, multiplies them together, and then takes the `SUMPRODUCT` of the results. Working out from the second set of nested terms:

- `C1:C5` returns the array `[100,5,120,3,26]`
- `C2:C6` (offset by one row) returns `[5,120,3,26,7]`

Multiplying these arrays gives the intermediate array:

- `[500,600,360,78,182]`

Which is each number in column C multiplied by the one after it. However only every other result (indicated by the value `"FC"` in column B) is to be included in the final sum. This is accomplished using the other nested term, which tests the value of each cell of the specified range in order:

- `B1:B5="FC"` returns the array `[TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE]`

Excel treats `TRUE/FALSE` values as `1/0` when multiplying (though not for addition/subtraction), so the `SUMPRODUCT` function sees:

- `[1,0,1,0,1]*[500,600,360,78,182]` => `[500,0,360,0,182]`

and then adds the values of the resulting products:

- `500 + 0 + 360 + 0 + 182` = `1042`

Comment: nice explanation.  I am being lazy today.  Good on you.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, a clever solution indeed! I may have oversimplified my example; in reality there are many other values between each instance of FC and ST, and consequently many of the results from `(C1:C5*C2:C6)` expression will return `#VALUE!` results and break the formula. Adding an `iferror()` component and confirming with Ctrl+Shift+Enter fixed everything up. Thanks again.

Comment: Simplifying to the simplest case to explain your question is not only great practice @tfunk10258, it is highly encouraged here when posting questions. And it's also a great way to break down and solve problems on your own before building back up to the actual (complex) usage. Glad you could see how to apply this approach, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

For this specific example.

```
{=SUM((IF(B1:B6="FC",C1:C6,0)*IF(B2:B7="ST",C2:C7,0)))}
```

This will only work if FC and ST alternate just like in the example. If it does not, you could quickly change it to fit this format by sorting column A primarily and column B secondarily.

Notice the array in the second if statement is offset by one cell. This allows the arrays to multiply in the manner desired. Also, since it is an array formula, make sure you use CTRL+SHIFT+Enter when you put it in its cell.